# open list of file names with "with" command creates not list of strings but a list of characters

Tags: python, list, with-statement

I have a file called `files.txt` with file names in it. Like this:

> L150216_1.txt_out
>
> L150216_2.txt_out
>
> L150216_3.txt_out

I am opening `files.txt` like this:

```
with open("files.txt") as f:
    file_List = f.read()
    pass #Do some calculations with the file_List
```

However, it turns out that the file_List looks not like a list of file names but a list of characters. I.e. instead of L150216_1.txt_out it would be L, 1, 5, 0 and so on.

How to open a file using `"with"` command so that it read lines, not characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in `with` command of Python, The unexpected behaviour is due to `read()`, If you really want to get the list of strings in various lines of the file being read then you must use `file.readlines()`.

```
with open("files.txt") as f:
    file_List = f.readlines()
    #Now file_List is a list as
    #["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]
    pass #Do some calculations with the file_List
```

Answer (score 0):

As a list comprehension:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('files.txt')]
```

However keep in mind that the spaces after each line will show up as `''` in the list